# Use of to-infinitive

Tags: usage, infinitives, to-infinitive

> I would like to travel places, **to see** the world and **to try** exquisite cuisines.
> Or
> I would like to travel places, **see** the world and **try** exquisite cuisines.

Is it necessary to use "to" for every verb or is it optional?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that we need a space after each comma.

> I would like to travel places, to see the world and to try exquisite cuisines.

> I would like to travel places, see the world and try exquisite cuisines.

With that, both examples are fine and meet the parallel construction requirements.

[Owl Purdue](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/parallel_structure.html) has a similar example.

> Mary likes to hike, to swim, and to ride a bicycle.

> Mary likes to hike, swim, and ride a bicycle.

> (Note: You can use "to" before all the verbs in a sentence or only before the first one.)

Comment: I would use "travel *to* places" but it may be only my personal quirk.

Comment: @Dan - I'd consider omitting the first 'to' as being a US usage. As a Brit, I'd never leave out the first one.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. I'm not sure what you mean by "the first to". But as a British person I certainly wouldn't make "travel" a transitive verb. One travels "to places". It is the same in French, and one suspects it takes the Latin dative.

Comment: @WS2 - sorry, yes, not too clear. I meant omitting to from "to travel **to** places" makes it sound US to me.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, both usages are correct. As a side note, as a Brit, I would prefer 'to travel to places' rather than omit the second 'to', but I would consider that a stylistic choice.
Ignoring that, I would maintain that each version simply uses different emphasis.

The first sets each desire as a separate task.
The second lumps them all together in one total task.
In this particular case, they could all be achieved in one overall event - that by travelling you would encompass seeing the world & trying different cuisines.

Imagine the tasks were more disparate, perhaps

> I'd like to cycle to Scotland, to juggle with fire and to fly a kite.

Though these could perhaps be accomplished on the same journey, the achievement of any one would not automatically include the others. Omitting the additional 'to' from your bucket list would then perhaps imply you were going to attempt them all in the same journey if not simultaneously - which would be quite a feat.

> I'd like to cycle to Scotland, juggle with fire and fly a kite.

Of course, if you wished to emphatically complete this feat as one incontrovertible single task, you would use

> I'd like to cycle to Scotland, juggling with fire and flying a kite.

… which may raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are grammatically correct, but the second is better style.

In English, we prefer to avoid any unnecessary repetition. In the first sentence, "to" is unnecessarily repeated twice. In the second, there is no unnecessary repetition, so it sounds much better.